# Fake video from saab

Tags: false-advertising, uae, government-contracts

https://web.archive.org/web/20230715091936/https://forums.flightsimulator.com/t/fake-gripen-video/599765

See above. Saab released a video falsely claiming the gripen turned 9g. It was actually a 4g turn.

Do the customers of the gripen have the right to sue the company for false advertising?

Comment: You can't possibly buy a Saab Gripen as a private person, because that stuff is military hardware and they only sell the fighter plane to countries. Plus, where do you get your number from?

Comment: From the link obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

There is no reason for anyone to believe that a country's Air Force would purchase a military jet fighter in reliance upon a comment made by the company  in a promotional video intended for the general public. And, even if it did, generally "buyer beware" applies to international purchases of military equipment. It would not be reasonable for the UAE to rely on the video in question as authoritative. And, I very much doubt that the specifications of the jet fighter provided by the seller to the UAE military said the same thing.

Comment: Interesting. There actually were advertisements for the f15 to private individuals.

Comment: @DhdhUsuss Perhaps there are exceptions, but I would certainly expect the sales to be highly regulated. At a minimum I'd expect that the seller would have to strip out military hardware to effectively make it a civilian version. Of course, that's tangential to the answer in any case.

Comment: If a pilot on a military sees a YouTube video and decides to do something stupid they can die.

Comment: @DhdhUsuss A military whose pilots rely on YouTube videos for flight instruction and parameters has it coming to them when their pilots die.

Comment: So then the liability would be on the military training bureaucracy and not youtube or saab.

Comment: @DhdhUsuss Military forces are immune from liability for training accidents in most places (as, for that matter, are most employers of all kinds public and private). There would generally be a program of survivor's benefits for military personnel who die in the line of duty including training accidents, as part of  the employment benefits package of being a member of the military.

Comment: But somebody would be fired or something for using YouTube.

Comment: Also, remember Grissoms family sued for his death, I think that is similar.

Comment: @DhdhUsuss You can't fire somebody when they're dead.

Comment: This isn't a joke question, Nellis air force base literally uses a specific youtube channel based on a video game for training.

Comment: Grissom didn't sue the government and wouldn't have prevailed under current law. which would grant the contractor waivers of liability. https://www.nytimes.com/2018/10/11/obituaries/betty-grissom-dead.html

Comment: I see. However many non American airforce contract heavily and it would be the same. I wouldn't be surprised if saab did its own training and used videos.

Comment: @DhdhUsuss "This isn't a joke question," I'm not claiming otherwise. But it is patently unreasonable for an Air Force to rely upon the accuracy of a promotional video for the general public to determine the specifications of fighter jets that it purchased. A lawsuit based on that would be thrown out of court in short order. Also, it isn't false advertising if the ads are made after you sold the fighter jets.

Comment: I see, I'm just saying it's something that could happen. Some Saudi prince dies based on faulty training from a western contractor that gave them a youtube video.

Comment: @DhdhUsuss Even if the dude is not a prince, training a fighter pilot is incredibly expensive, because so much training with expensive equipment is necessary. Credulous pilots who would believe that and were reckless enough to try it out would ordinarily wash out of training long before a fighter jet is put in their hands. High tech simulators built by the company building the planes and not YouTube videos are the norm in flight training. If the Saudis want to cut corners in flight training, that's good luck for anyone who wants to go to war with them. No need to shed tears for them.

Comment: @DhdhUsuss I don't know what the law is in Sweden. But in the U.S. there are precedents holding that the rulings of courts in places like Saudi Arabia and UAE are not entitled to any recognition because those countries aren't governed by the rule of law and are instead absolute monarchies.

Comment: Yes that makes sense.